# using "without" for replacing "unless"

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

> Unless I have any breakfast, I will be hungry at work.

Can I change this sentence, using "without"?

> E.g- Without having any breakfast, I will be hungry at work.

Is it natural for using "without" to rephrase the "unless" structure?

Answer (score 4):

You could say:

> *Without breakfast, I will be hungry at work.*

If using 'unless' like in your first sentence, you don't need the 'any' (you could also replace the 'any' with 'some'):

> *Unless I have (some) breakfast, I will be hungry at work.*

But I would say that the most natural way to phrase this sentence would be:

> *If I don't have breakfast, I will be hungry at work.*